# Adding an admin role to a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I recently created a small rails app using Rails Composer with devise.

I then followed the guide to an admin attribute to the users table using this guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role.

I'm struggling with this one thing:

in app/views/layouts/_nav_links_for_auth.html.erb, I have:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
    <li> <%= link_to 'Users', users_path %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have set the attribute to true for the user I'm logged in as - however, the statement if current_user.try(:admin?) above doesn't return true. I've doubled checked in the sqlite development database that the attribute is actually set to true, and it is.

So, I'm stuck. As best I can figure out, it doesn't know what actually is an "admin". In my user model, I have this (which was there by default):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  ...
end
```

I'd love some help with getting to this work. What do I need to do?

Comment: can u update the `set_default_role`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have an `enum` if you have an explicit `admin` attribute for your `User` model?

If you're using `enum`, you'd have a `role` attribute, which will give you methods such as `admin?`, or you need to have an explicit `admin` attribute - which you should have if you have fired the `migration` that you posted.

To clear up any potential confusion, [**enum**](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) is used if you have strict criteria for a column, and only wish your users to have certain values assigned to it. `Roles` is a great example:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum role: [:admin, :user] #-> requires "role" column which will store either :admin (0) or :user (1) values
end
```

---

In your case, you have several issues.

Firstly, `boolean` columns create appropriate methods in your model for *that* column...
Having `admin` as a `boolean` column will give you `@user.admin?` method.

```
<%= content_tag :li, link_to('Users', users_path) if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
```

This is what you should use *if* you have the migration as you stated from the `Devise` link (IE you have an `admin` boolean column)

--

The second problem you have is that you're getting confused in your model.

*IF* you wanted to have a default role, and have potential roles defined with an `enum`, you'd want to use the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
   # remove after_init callback
end
```

You'd set a *default* role by setting the `role` default value in your db:

```
$ rails g migration SetDefaultRole

#db/migrate/set_default_role_______.rb
class SetDefaultRole < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 1
   end
end

$ rails db:migrate #-> if you're using Rails 5
$ rake db:migrate #-> Rails 4+
```

Comment: Thank you Rich that makes total sense and I now understand what the issue is. From your answer I was able to get the attribute working, but have also decided to use an actual role for admin. In my case, as I used Rails Composer with Devise, it already had an admin role and I simply didn't know (since this is my first time adding authentication into my rails app) that all I had to do was set the admin role in the database. I guess a follow up question would now be, instead of setting the role in the database directly, what's the best way to set it? Thank you!

Comment: No problem, hope you have a great christmas

Answer (score 0):

You could use either the `role` enum or the `admin` attribute but not both.

The problem in your case is that the `admin?` method being called is the one that is defined by enum (which checks the role) rather than `admin?` method provided by activerecord for boolean columns.

So though your `admin` column is true, your role is not being set to admin (for reasons we can not investigate because your `set_default_role` implementation is not available).

I recommend adopting a role based system, investigating why the correct role is not being set and then getting rid of the `admin` column.

Comment: Thank you - this is very clear to me now. For set_default_role I have: 

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end